# How to use LOINC codes on FHIR

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't access LOINC codes on my Smart FHIR project.

I've found LOINC codes which I need. I tried by looking at tutorials. But the result I want is blank.

```
var chol = byCodes('86911-5');
var hemog = byCodes('86910-7');
//another function
var p = defaultPatient();
p.chol = getQuantityValueAndUnit(chol[0]);
p.hemog = getQuantityValueAndUnit(hemog[0]);
```

I want to get the value of Hemoglobin A1C and total Cholesterol

//I didn't show the functions. Functions and their names are copied from the
 documentation of Smart FHIR, so there is not any problem on functions

Comment: any error you got in your browser console while running these codes?

Comment: any errors. just blank <p> tag